# Error passing variable from another module

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have been trying to pass a variable from one module to another in Python but I get an error.

afile.py

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master, *args):
        .....

    def browse_file(self):
        self.filename = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.textfile.config(text=self.filename)
```

bfile.py

```
import pandas as pd
from afile import Window

df = pd.read_html(Window.filename, encoding='utf-8')[0]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need an instance of `Window` in order to access its instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` is a class, but in your `bfile.py` it has not be instantiated to create an object.

The `.filename` object attributes does not exist until after the object has been initialized. (You *can* have class attributes, but that is not in your code.) You need to first create the object, then access the attribute.

The `Window.__init__` method requires an argument called `master`.  You will need to pass in something there to get your object created.

```
import pandas as pd
from afile import Window

df = pd.read_html(Window(master=???).filename, encoding='utf-8')[0]
```

Comment: in the order of functionality I should import from the bfile a function with readhtml, or the way I am doing it is correct?

Comment: The way you are doing it looks fine